# Как отправлять POST запрос на сервер через PHP со своими параметрами?

Tags: php, json, post

Можно ли отправлять `POST` запрос со своего сервера на другой, при этом эмулируя другое устройство? Хочу автоматизировать процесс получения плюшек в приложении и смог получить их `GET` и `POST` запросы, осталось правильно их отправлять со своего сервера. 
Отправка из приложения осуществляется примерно таким способом:

```json
POST /prozone HTTP/1.1
Host: 185.47.152.162:82
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: delivermore/2.0.51 (iPhone; iOS 10.3.2; Scale/2.00)
Accept-Language: ru-BY;q=1, en-BY;q=0.9
Content-Length: 76
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

{
  "answer_id" : 177,
  "session_id" : "токен"
}
```

Comment: используйте CURL.

Comment: @Эдуард, через него можно эмулировать мобильный браузер?

Comment: да, можно задавать любое имя браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте cURL, формируете обычный POST-запрос с требуемыми параметрами, cookies и т.д. В запросе можно задать заголовки, которые придут на сервер (User Agent и т.д.), IP-адрес (если используете HTTP или SOCKS5 прокси) и еще много чего.

Comment: А можете привести пример как сформировать эти настройки? А то я знаю как отправлять cURLом только без них.

Comment: для выполнения POST-запроса используйте CURLOPT_POST => true, по другим настройкам можно почитать более подробно официальную документацию по curl (php.net, смотрите раздел с cURL).